# fileReader() API broken on all browsers I have

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, filereader

[image: errorAlert on image select]

So that's the error. It's quite self explanitory, but I cannot for the life of me work out how this is possible?

The code hasn't changed for this part of my site in a long time, it was working a few months ago, I decided to check over alll the bits and fix bugs etc and this happened.

I was in Firefox at the time but I have since tried it on 3 chromium browsers too (namely Chrome, Brave and Edge) & Opera all with the same result?

I also tried it on my phone with the same result in case it was my PC doing something strange.

It's literally erroring on the creation of a `new fileReader();` event.

This isn't even part of my code I don't think. How can any browser not support something that has been in the browsers capability for decades?

Someone please shed some light on this.

Peace

Robbie

**EDIT** As requested code in question:

```
function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                url: target.result,
                orientation: 4,
                zoom: 0,
                viewport: {
                    width: 500,
                    height: 500,
                    type: 'square'
                },
                    boundary: {
                    height: 300
                }   

            }).then(function(){
                console.log('jQuery bind complete');
            });

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
        swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
    }
}
```

Comment: "*It's quite self explanitory*" no, it's not. I am not a browser. It's quite baffling to be told I am. In addition, it's completely unclear what code is causing the error that calls me a browser. If the code really is `new fileReader();`, then the problem is that starts with a capital: `new FileReader()`. However, if that is a typo in the question but not the code, we cannot identify the error in an unseen and unknowable code.

Comment: ok that's a typo i didn't copy paste, but if you require the code I'll happily copy it here, but the fact that it errors with does not support, says it comes from the instance of trying to use said API no, not anything you may or may not do with that data afterwards.

Comment: We have no idea *how* it is trying to use the API. It could be that it's doing `try { new FileReader(); throw Error("todo: fix later"); } catch (err) { showFileReaderErrorToUser(); }`

Comment: in fact looking at it pasted the F is indeed capitalised

Comment: With the code it's completely clear that `new FileReader();` has *nothing* to do with the error. That code is inside the `if`, the error is in the `else`. So, it means `input.files && input.files[0]` is `false`

Comment: that's weird cos it I changed nothing in this file. I'll see if it works now and then close the question. tyvm VLAZ

Comment: Yeah I'm realising it's an error from that too. Don't worry, thanks for the help. That's not even the actual code that executes, but i'm now actually tracking it down. That is from the orignal copy/paste /modification from croppie and it's a bit differnet in the deployed bit, but the error is the same for the same reason. input.files is not working

Comment: $(document).on('change', '#jobPic', ()=> { readFile(this); $('.picPreview').show(); }); This is where it comes from and it doesn't make sense that the input var is not a file... alas i'll find it

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found my problem, thanks to VLAZ for ponting out my coded folly. So the solution is now here below.

1st FileReader() has to be capitalised for croppie for whatever reason.

The real problem was in the jQuery trigger, I had changed my anonymous function syntax with a find and replace without realising it was affecting some things and so.
I had to change this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#jobPic', ()=> { readFile(this); $('.picPreview').show(); });
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#jobPic', function () { readFile(this); $('.picPreview').show(); });
```

Simple fail. Classic.